# angular meteor (version1 .3.9) : Unable to resolve module "underscore"

Tags: meteor, underscore.js, angular-meteor, atmosphere.js, meteor-packages

Angular-meteor was updated yesterday, until then everything was running just fine. Today I fired up "meteor update" and I am suddenly seeing errors when running meteor. Most notably this one:

```
Unable to resolve some modules:

  "underscore" in                             
.meteor/packages/angular-meteor-data/.1.3.9.1d745lo++os+web.browser+web.cordova/web.browser/.npm/package/node_modules/angular-meteor/dist/angular-meteor.js
(web.browser)
  "jsondiffpatch" in                          
.meteor/packages/angular-meteor-data/.1.3.9.1d745lo++os+web.browser+web.cordova/web.browser/.npm/package/node_modules/angular-meteor/dist/angular-meteor.js
(web.browser)
  "angular" in                                
.meteor/packages/dotansimha_accounts-ui-angular/.0.0.4.1i02c2b++os+web.browser+web.cordova/web.browser/accounts-ui-angular.js
(web.browser)
```

I have no idea where this is coming from nor what I can do to fix this. Can / should I rollback to an old version or did I do something that isn't obvious at first glance ?

Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it with the new angular-meteor `1.3.9_2` version.
Should be fixed there.